# Recognizing an integer as a float in 2 dimensional array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, subscript

Here's the code that I'm currently using

```
template <class T>
float Knapsack<T>::knapTable()
{
  const int MAXSIZE = 40000;
  int temps = nObjects - 1;
  float** memoize = new float*[MAXSIZE];

  for(int y = 0; y < weight[nObjects]; y++)
    memoize[nObjects][y] = 0;

  for(int y = weight[nObjects]; y < knapCap; y++)
    memoize[nObjects][y] = price[y];

  for(int i = temps; i >= 1; i--)
  {
    for(int y = weight[i]; y < knapCap; y++)
      memoize[i][y]= max(memoize[i+1][y], (memoize[i+1][y-weight[i]]+price[i]));
  }

  return memoize[1][nObjects];

}
```

For some reason I keep getting the error: knapsack.hpp:68:64: error: invalid types ‘float*[float]’ for array subscript.

That's this line:   float** memoize = new float*[MAXSIZE];

For some reason the compiler seems to be recognizing MAXSIZE as a float, it's a const int.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Edited for more code
header file
    #ifndef KNAPSACK_H
    #define KNAPSACK_H

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Knapsack
{
  private:
    float knapPrice;
    int knapCap, nObjects;
    float weight[40000];
    float price[40000];
  public:

    Knapsack(): knapPrice(0), knapCap(0), nObjects(0) {}
    ~Knapsack() {knapPrice = 0; knapCap = 0;}

    float knapFull (int position, int currentCap);

    float knapTable ();

    float greedyKnap (int currentCap);

    float max(float noAdd,float addOb);

    void printPrice();
    //valueized and valued are modified versions of mergeSort and merge
    //designed to sort two arrays by a fraction of the two.
    void valueize(int ini, int last);

    void valued(int ini, int middle, int last);

    void fillWandP();

    void setNObjects(int n);

    void setKnapCap(int boom);
};
#include "knapsack.hpp"
#endif
```

Main function //Though I don't think this would affect it
    #include "sortClass.h"
    #include "knapsack.h"
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
//mergeSort main;
int main()
{
    Knapsack<float> a;
    float sacked = 0;

    int nO = 18;
    int cap = 700;
    a.setNObjects(nO);

a.setKnapCap(cap);

    a.fillWandP();

    for(int b = 0; b <3800000; b++)//for getting good times
  sacked = b;

    int startAll = clock()*1000000;
    sacked = a.knapFull(1, cap);
    int knapped = clock()*1000000;
    int boom = a.knapTable();
    int tabled = clock()*1000000;
    a.valueize(1, cap);
    int andDone = a.greedyKnap(cap);
    int greedified = clock()*1000000;
    cout<<startAll<<endl;

    greedified = greedified - tabled;
    tabled = tabled - knapped;
    knapped = knapped - startAll;
    cout<<"Recursion profit:"<<sacked<<" Time: "<<knapped<<endl;
    cout<<"Memoization profit:"<<boom<<" Time: "<<tabled<<endl;
    cout<<"Greedy profit: "<<andDone<<" Time: "<<greedified<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate this with the simplified code: `const int MAXSIZE = 40000; float **memoize = new float*[MAXSIZE];` Perhaps something else is wrong? Are you defining `MAXSIZE` anywhere else?

Comment: Agreed -- I couldn't duplicate this, using g++ 4.4.5. Sample program: `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        const int MAXSIZE = 40000;
        float** memoize = new float*[MAXSIZE];

        cout << "Pointer address: " << memoize << endl;
        return 0;
}`

Comment: MAXSIZE is only defined once and even if I were to put a number in the brackets (i.e. 2000) it keeps giving me the same error. This is also true if I declare it like so: {float memoize[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];} Edit: also true if I change 'memoize'

Comment: What if you say `float **memoize = new float*[2000];`?

Comment: Which line is line 68? Because I seriously doubt that line would give that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weight` is declared as `float weight[40000]` in `class Knapsack`.

You then use an element of `weight` as an index into `memoize` in the `knaptable()` function:

```
memoize[i][y]= max(memoize[i+1][y], (memoize[i+1][y-weight[i]]+price[i]));
//                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

And for the record, that's the line that the error is produced for by g++ 4.6.1; it doesn't point to the line where `memoize` is declared.

Comment: Thank you this was my problem. Guess I should pay a little more attention to line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily related, but you're not using your arrays/pointers correctly. You create your first level of pointers when you call `float** memoize = new float*[MAXSIZE]` but you then just have an array of pointers, not a double array. You need to initialize each of `memoize[i]` as an array as well.

That being said, it doesn't look like you should be allocating memory for your `memoize` array anyway. Just declare it as

```
float memoize[SIZE][SIZE];
```

That way, you won't have to worry about memory cleanup or anything, and it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Attempted like that the first time the error was similar, however it only recognize the second [MAXSIZE] as a float and no the first one.   This was the error: error: invalid types ‘float [40000][float]’ for array subscript

Comment: @user1787163 What is the error it is giving you? And perhaps you could show us some more code? I can't figure out why that would be giving you an error from the code you've shown.

Comment: I'm not sure if my code will be that much help, I have a lot of functions so I'll post what I believe is relevant

Comment: What is the error you get if you write `float memoize[2000][2000];`?

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(int i = temps; i >= 1; i--)
  {
    for(int y = weight[i]; y < knapCap; y++)
      memoize[i][y]= max(memoize[i+1][y], (memoize[i+1][y-weight[i]]+price[i]));
  }
```

`y-weight[i]` is a float.  This is your problem.

Once you fix this you will discover that you still have an issue, you're allocating an array of pointers but you also need to allocate the **second dimension** for each of those pointers before you can use that array.

Something along the lines of:

```
float** memoize = new float*[MAXSIZE];

for(size_t i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
{
  memoize[i] = new float[MAXSIZE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think maybe you just need to allocate memory for the second pointer ,something like

```
float** memoize = new float*[MAXSIZE];
    memoize=(float**)malloc(sizeof(float*)*MAXSIZE);
    for(int i=0;i<MAXSIZE;i++)
    {
        memoize[i]=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*MAXSIZE);
    }
```